# Otros Log Viewer pattern for log4j

Tags: logging, log4j

I'm trying to use the following log pattern setup with [Otros Log Viewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/Log4jPatternLayout):

```
type=log4j
patternn=TIMESTAMP LEVEL [CLASS] (THREAD) MESSAGE
dateFormat=MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS
name=IDP JBoss Log
charset=utf-8
```

However, but when I click "Test parser", the status line at the bottom of the screen says "0 events parsed!" I've also tried omitting the charset property, but that has no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I've pasted into the left-hand pane:

```
12-07 08:38:18,116 TRACE [com.company.security.MyLoginModule] (WorkerThread#6) commit, loginOk=true
12-07 09:08:17,738 TRACE [com.company.security.MyLoginModule] (WorkerThread#6) logout
12-07 09:08:17,739 TRACE [com.company.security.MyLoginModule] (WorkerThread#6) initialize
12-07 09:08:17,739 TRACE [com.company.security.MyLoginModule] (WorkerThread#6) Saw unauthenticatedIdentity=null
12-07 09:08:17,739 TRACE [com.company.security.MyLoginModule] (WorkerThread#6) login
12-07 09:08:17,742 TRACE [com.company.security.MyLoginModule] (WorkerThread#6) Logging into LDAP server
```

Comment: Thanks. Proper error reporting was added: http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/issues/detail?id=248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have miss-typed "pattern". Replace "patternn" with "pattern".